# Google Chrome removes itself from Menu on reboot

Tags: menu, google-chrome

Chrome removes itself from the Internet menu every time I reboot. How can I fix this? The only way to get it back is to reinstall Chrome. Is this a Dev issue or a general error?

I am using Ubuntu 10.04.1 with Gnome. Chrome is the 6.0.495.0 dev version. I downloaded it here: http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel

Comment: What desktop are you using? Gnome, KDE, Xfce, ...? Which release of Ubuntu do you use? what is the package release of chrome, where do you get it from?

Comment: Edited above....

Comment: Was this installation installed on a removeable storage device, such as a USB disk, or is it in your main home directory ? I'm wondering whether the installed location might not be a permanently available one, that could therefore get it removed from the main menu ? Can you create an icon on your own desktop, and does it remain on the desktop ? If it does remain on the desktop but not on the application menu, there might be an issue around the rights to create documents in some directories.

Comment: Note: 6.0.495.0 is only currently available in the google-chrome-unstable package.  While I don't know if Chrome is causing this particular issue, you may be happier with google-chrome-beta, which is slightly behind -unstable (currently 6.0.472.36).  (Chrome adds Google's repositories, using /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list, when you install from .deb, so you can easily use aptitude/synaptic/etc. to switch—just back up ~/.config/google-chrome first.)

Comment: I'm using Chrome 5.0.375.127 on Linux Mint 9 (Ubunty 10) with no similar issue. Have you updated the kernel since a fresh install? Sometimes that can cause some strange quirks in the OS.

Comment: This is in no way a fix, but my chrome launcher sits just to the right of my Gnome `System` menu where it belongs ;) Oddly, I've used chrome dev-channel releases on two machines running Lucid and Maverick with stable, beta_current, and dev_current with no issues and it never left Applications➔Internet➔Google Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create new item on menu list. fill Name with >> Chromium Web Browser, fill Command with >> chromium-browser %U

close the Menu Editor, and now Chromium shortcut will appear on your main Menu. ;)

Comment: This is a workaround, which is good, but it also needs to be fixed in the package

Comment: This works for now so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bug in Chrome itself. This person has [reported a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-menus/+bug/598711) in Launchpad with some information that might be useful. You should grab the information from that bug and [file a bug](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines) in Google Chrome.

Comment: Isn't that a packaging bug? If so it should probably stay in lauchpad and solved by the maintainers..

Comment: It's a 3rd part deb, I would think the bug report would go to Google. However if someone can reproduce it in Chromium also then I would agree.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using Canonical's version of Chrome instead of Google's.  I know it's not going to be nearly as bleeding edge, but Google does not put a lot of effort into Ubuntu integration or testing, and this is only one of the types of problems you'll see from it.  Others include:
Incomplete useragent: "Linux", but not "Ubuntu"
Window controls on the wrong side
..and probably a lack of Ubuntu Menu bar support at some point, if Canonical modifies Chromium for Ubuntu Netbook Edition.  Seemingly little things, sure, but you've run into one and obviously decided it's worth fixing.

Comment: Your answer has some things you need to correct. In Chrome the window controls are either on the left or right depending on your theme with the current stable release. Also there's no such thing as "Canonical's version of Chrome" and also the menu bar support is still pending (we're working with them on that).

Comment: Interesting..  I'm kind of curious, could you expand on what you said about themes and working with Google on appmenu bar support?

Answer (score 0):

Why not try installing the ubuntu chromium-browser from [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/ppa) which is recommended by ethana2. Usually  *.desktop file located at /usr/share/applications/ can be edited for displaying in application menu

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but i solved it (for me).

If you are using the program "Prey" this might be the problem. Setting the 'Secure' option to OFF (in the 'actions to perform' section of your computer) fixed this problem for me.